# Como incrementar o nome de arquivo txt que será criado no php?

Tags: php

Se é que é possível, como incrementar o nome de arquivo txt no php? Estou trabalhando com php que conheço bem pouco, preciso incrementar o nome de um arquivo txt, para que seja criado um novo arquivo `json.txt` sempre que eu enviar um arquivo para o servidor. Alguém sabe como fazer isso? Estou tendo que incrementar na mão, estou no `json46.txt`.

```
$file = fopen('JSON46.txt', 'w'); // cria o arquivo json.txt
fwrite($file, $_POST['json']."\r\n\r\n\r\n");
```

Comment: Você quer trocar o nome do mesmo arquivo?

Comment: quero gerar arquivos incrementando o numero no nome por exemplo Json1.txt depois Json2.txt sempre incrementando o número.

Answer (score 1):

Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
//Primeiro você precisa de uma variável que conte.
$jsonIncremento = 0;

//aqui você concatena com o nome do arquivo.
$file = fopen('JSON' .$jsonIncremento. '.txt', 'w'); // cria o arquivo json.txt
fwrite($file, $_POST['json']."\r\n\r\n\r\n");

//depois a cada arquivo criado é so ir incrementando ela.
$jsonIncremento++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você não tem um controle em memória de qual número precisar, eu pensei na seguinte solução:

- Ler todos arquivos de um diretório.
- Faço um `regex` para pegar todos números no título.
- Procuro pelo maior número entre eles
- Retorno o próximo incremento que você precisa

```
$seuDiretorio = '/tmp'; /* exemplo */
$arqs = scandir($seuDiretorio);

$maior = 0;
foreach ($arqs as $arq) {
    $numeroArq = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', basename($arq));

    if ($numeroArq > $maior) {
        $maior = $numeroArq;
    }
}

echo 'Próximo Numero é '. ($maior + 1);
```

Desse jeito pra criar o próximo é só fazer:

```
$file = fopen('JSON'.($maior+1).'.txt', 'w');
```

Com este código você precisa ficar atento que no diretório só pode ter os arquivos que você está guardando com incremento.